# What is the difference between 「けれど」 and 「けれども」 and 「けど」?

Tags: word-choice

「けれども」と「けど」と「けれど」はいったいどう違うんですか。「けれども」はテレビ番組でよく使われているが、「けれども」は「けれど」より丁寧ですか。

***English translation:*** What exactly do 「けれども」 and 「けど」 and 「けれど」 mean? They often use 「けれども」 on TV programs, but is 「けれども」 more polite than 「けれど」?

Comment: My understanding is that this site is for English speakers learning Japanese. So while I felt that the original question was in simple enough Japanese to be good practice for learners of a certain level, we shouldn't exclude lower level learners who might also benefit from the question. Thus I edited the question to provide an English translation. I hope that is acceptable.

Comment: @Dave Sounds good to me

Answer (score 12):

`けど` is short for `けれど`, and hence, is colloquial and less polite. `けれども` has `も` 'even' added somewhat redundantly. I don't see clear differences between `けれど` and `けれども`. The difference among the three may be parallel to the difference among English `though`, `although`, and `even though`. So if a native English speaker can tell the difference among them, it may be a clue for telling the difference for the Japanese words.

Comment: The English examples you give here are perfectly interchangeable, just as けれども and its variants are (ignoring politeness levels). Also, **けども** does pop up occasionally, but the infrequency with which I hear it leads me to believe it is more dialectical than standard.

Comment: @sawa, @Derek: けど is short for けれど? Really? You guys just blew my mind. I never knew that. I always thought けど was it's own thing, and use it a lot, especially in the form だけど, or　ですけど when connecting sentences (as in "this, *but* that"). Can I say ですけれど？　Is だけれど silly because けれど is more formal than だ？

Comment: @Dave M G: Yes. ですけど, ですけれど, and ですけれども are semantically equivalent, as are だけど, だけれど, and だけれども. The usual rule of "longer = more polite" applies.

Answer (score 4):

けれど is 98% used only in writings.
It’s slightly more polite than けど, though, it sounds awkward if you use it in conversations.

For example, if you want to say “I’d like to visit Japan but I’m too busy”,
you would say “日本にはいきたい**けど**、忙しすぎる。" in a conversation with your friend whereas you would write “日本には行きたい**けれど**、忙し過ぎるんです。” in your blog, which should be a little more polite.

**けれども** is definitely more polite than these two, and is used in both speakings and writings.

けれども can be used for someone like your customers or boss, but not for presidents or priests. For those people or in a formal situation where you should be very polite (not necessarily with priests but with people you have to be polite to), “**ですが**“ is usually used instead.

As for the levels of politeness,
けど(informal)<けれど(only in writings)<けれども(polite/formal)<ですが(very polite/formal)

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in how polite they are. The longer the word, the more polite it is.

The shorter a word, the more curt and impolite it is.

Comment: so, "が" is very impolite?

Comment: @Axioplase: が, though it can mean the same thing as the けれども series, is a separate construction with only one form, and so it can be used in any (polite/informal/spoken/written) setting. "longer = more polite" applies most of the time, but not all the time.

Comment: @Derek: yes, I know.  I was just cynically commenting the assertion about concision and politeness.

Comment: @Axioplase: Ah, I missed the </not-a-real-question> tag there. My bad. :)

Comment: Actually just putting か at the end of a sentence to turn it into a question is impolite if you don't lengthen it by other things behind it.

Comment: @languagehacker He said が, not か (mind the dakuten).